# Initdb for PostgreSql gives shmget error

Tags: macos, postgresql, shared-memory

I am migrating from Win to Mac and have PostgreSql 9.2.4 installed on Mac X 10.8.3 through Homebrew

When I run the initdb command

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

I get the following error

```
DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=1, size=2072576, 03600).
HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded 
available memory or swap space, or exceeded your kernel's SHMALL parameter.  You can either 
reduce the request size or reconfigure the kernel with larger SHMALL.  To reduce the request 
size (currently 2072576 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing 
shared_buffers or max_connections.
```

In researching I found this thread

[Setting SHMMAX etc values on MAC OS X 10.6 for PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017004/setting-shmmax-etc-values-on-mac-os-x-10-6-for-postgresql)

and figured I will increase the shmall and hopefully that will help but I get the same error as above with the configuration below.

Contents of my /etc/sysctl.conf file are

```
kern.sysv.shmmax=33554432
kern.sysv.shmmin=1
kern.sysv.shmmni=256
kern.sysv.shmseg=64
kern.sysv.shmall=8192
```

Assuming the shmall is blocks of 4096 I seem to have more than enough memory for shmget unless bunch of it is being used by other parts of my system. The activity monitor shows I have more than 6GB free memory left.

Perhaps there is something basic I am missing here.

Thanks for your help.

-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`ipcs -m`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ipcs.1.html) command to know how much shared memory is already used out of `shmmax` (`33554432` bytes).

Presumably it's near the maximum. The unused 6GB don't help if shmmax is so small.

Personally I wouldn't bother with such small values. Increase `shmmax` at something like 4Gb, `shmall` at the corresponding 1 million. There isn't any practical drawback to have high values.

Comment: I increased the shmmax and shmall to 4G and 1 million as you suggested Daniel and that resolved the problem. Thanks.